# Search form by start_time and end_time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My models

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many: bookings
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to: house
end
```

The booking table has the fields customer_name, start_time, end_time ect.

I want to make a search form (start_time, end_time) on the houses page index page so the visitor can check which houses are available for the given period.

Has someone ideas how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a view, declare a form non linked to any object

```
<% form_tag :url => search_book_path, :method => :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :start_time %>
  <%= text_field_tag :end_time %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Add a route on books

```
map.resource :books, :collection => { search => :get }
```

In the book_controller, declare the function search:

```
def search
  start_time = params[:start_time] || DateTime.now
  end_time = params[:end_time] || DateTime.now
  @books = Book.search(start_time, end_time)
end
```

Then declare the search on Book model

```
def search(start_time_, end_time_)
  return Book.find(:all, :conditions => [
       "#{Book.table_name}.start_time >= ? AND #{book.table_name}.end_time <= ?",
       start_time_,
       end_time_]
  )
end
```

Not sure about all the syntax, but this should give you an idea.

Edit: I didn't understand all the problem. The model function `search` should search available houses that:

- are not used at the required begin date : book.end_time < start_time_
- are not booked at the required end date : book.start_time > end_time_

Like this

```
def search_for_availability_between(start_time_, end_time_)
  return Book.find(:all, :conditions => [
       "#{Book.table_name}.start_time > ? AND #{book.table_name}.end_time < ?",
       end_time_,
       start_time_]
  )
end
```

You should check it by tests, but I think it should work.

Comment: thanks man!.this is a good start/base...but what's the best approach when a house is booked/reserved for a the given period, so this house must not show in the search results....

Comment: thanks!..but what i don't understand..why not creating an additional column or table in which the booked days/weeks are stored? I don't understand your...solution....

Comment: @Remco It's an other complete problem. Finding available houses with bookings data is possible and easy, but takes time to explain. You should open an other question.

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
@books = Book.available_house(start_time, end_time)
```

in Book model you can use scope

in House Model

```
def available_house(start, finish)
  where("id not in (select t.house_id from timings t where (t.start_time between ? and ?) || (t.end_time between ? and ?) )", start,finish,start,finish)
end
```

Comment: thanks man!.this is a good start/base...but what's the best approach when a house is booked/reserved for a the given period, so this house must not show in the search results....

Comment: i have changed above code for finding house available on that time